# Micrometer traceId and spanId are missing with log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, micrometer, distributed-tracing, micrometer-tracing

after I migrated my app from spring boot 2.7 to 3.1.5, I am not able to log traceId and spanId to the logger.

I migrated sleuth to micromerter, as described in migration guide and edited the log4j2.xml file to recommended format `[%X{traceId:-}, %X{spanId:-}]` but it is not logged as you can see bellow:

```
2023-11-01 16:38:15.854+0100 [level=INFO ][,]  INFO MBP-14 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] com.example.demo.Controller : Hello, World!
```

vs

```
2023-11-01 16:38:42.896+0100 [level=INFO ][{spanId=fb964679c404b92f, traceId=fb964679c404b92f}]  INFO MBP-14 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] com.example.demo.Controller : Hello, World!
```

2.7.7 dependencies:

```
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2021.0.8"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude(module = "logback-classic")
        exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "slf4j-log4j12")
    }
}
```

3.1.5 dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave")
    implementation("io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude(module = "logback-classic")
        exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "slf4j-log4j12")
    }
}
```

I prepared repo [here](https://github.com/mkubele/tracing) with branches *2.7* and *3.1* where it can be reproduced by calling the *hello* endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation()` has to be added to the `main()` function and then it works

Comment: If you are using Webflux then this is working. Just use %X{traceId}  %X{spanId} in your log pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the log4j config that Spring Boot prepares for you so whatever you do in the `logging.pattern.level` property us useless.

The easiest fix is deleting the `log4j2-spring.xml` file and setting the following property:

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]
```

If you need that file please check the docs how to include back the Spring Boot log4j2 config files.

Comment: I actually tried removing the log4j2-spring.xml file in the demo project, but the ids are still not logged.

Comment: Set `management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0`, you can find samples here: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples

Comment: I use webflux and that is not covered in the samples. Is it possible to create a semple for this?

Comment: You mean this? https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples/tree/main/webflux